# SIGSEV on lots of GUI-software on arch linux. Seems to be glibc related

Tags: arch-linux, glibc, segmentation-fault

On my arch linux install, I can't open firefox, evolution, geary, midori and other software. All CLI-stuff I've tried works flawlessly, and also google-chrome-unstable, vlc and others. When ran in gdb (output below), the culprit seems to be `0x00007ffff7de63e1 in _dl_relocate_object () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, which I guess is in glibc.

I've updated the system, reinstalled glibc and affected applications (with pacman), the CPU seems fine and is up to date (this is not the Haswell-bug), arch linux from usb works fine.

Here's output of gdb for firefox and evolution with backtraces:

```
Gdb on firefox:

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from firefox...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/firefox 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

(process:5517): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
[New Thread 0x7fffd57fe700 (LWP 5551)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd5fff700 (LWP 5550)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd71b6700 (LWP 5549)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd8efc700 (LWP 5548)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd96fd700 (LWP 5547)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd9efe700 (LWP 5546)]
[New Thread 0x7fffda6ff700 (LWP 5545)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe037c700 (LWP 5543)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdc9ff700 (LWP 5542)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdd7fe700 (LWP 5541)]
[New Thread 0x7fffddfff700 (LWP 5540)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdeaff700 (LWP 5539)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdfc76700 (LWP 5538)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdfcf7700 (LWP 5537)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdfd78700 (LWP 5536)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdfdf9700 (LWP 5535)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdfe7a700 (LWP 5534)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdfefb700 (LWP 5533)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdff7c700 (LWP 5532)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdfffd700 (LWP 5531)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe007e700 (LWP 5530)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe00ff700 (LWP 5529)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe03fd700 (LWP 5528)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe15fd700 (LWP 5527)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe0bfe700 (LWP 5526)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe13ff700 (LWP 5525)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe4f10700 (LWP 5524)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7de63e1 in _dl_relocate_object () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7de63e1 in _dl_relocate_object () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#1  0x00007ffff7dee5a9 in dl_open_worker () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#2  0x00007ffff7de9f94 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#3  0x00007ffff7dede01 in _dl_open () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x00007ffff79bafc9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libdl.so.2
#5  0x00007ffff7de9f94 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x00007ffff79bb5e1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libdl.so.2
#7  0x00007ffff79bb061 in dlopen () from /usr/lib/libdl.so.2
#8  0x00007ffff19be58b in PR_LoadLibraryWithFlags () from /usr/lib/libnspr4.so
#9  0x00007ffff419af10 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#10 0x00007ffff419cf5b in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#11 0x00007ffff418adb8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#12 0x00007ffff418a7d1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#13 0x00007ffff55532bb in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#14 0x00007ffff5553163 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#15 0x00007ffff55530ac in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#16 0x00007ffff5372d39 in NS_InvokeByIndex () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#17 0x00007ffff4da4e83 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#18 0x00007ffff4da6a12 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#19 0x00007ffff5191fdc in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#20 0x00007ffff5185282 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#21 0x00007ffff518456f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#22 0x00007ffff519216c in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#23 0x00007ffff52f9a5f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#24 0x00007ffff5191fdc in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#25 0x00007ffff5195e12 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#26 0x00007ffff53318d6 in js::proxy_Call(JSContext*, unsigned int, JS::Value*) () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#27 0x00007ffff5192085 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#28 0x00007ffff5185282 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#29 0x00007ffff518456f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#30 0x00007ffff519216c in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#31 0x00007ffff5195d33 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#32 0x00007ffff53318d6 in js::proxy_Call(JSContext*, unsigned int, JS::Value*) () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#33 0x00007ffff5192085 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#34 0x00007ffff5185282 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#35 0x00007ffff518456f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#36 0x00007ffff519216c in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#37 0x00007ffff52f9a5f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#38 0x00007ffff5191fdc in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#39 0x00007ffff5195e12 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#40 0x00007ffff53318d6 in js::proxy_Call(JSContext*, unsigned int, JS::Value*) () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#41 0x00007ffff5192085 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#42 0x00007ffff5185282 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#43 0x00007ffff518456f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#44 0x00007ffff519216c in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#45 0x00007ffff5195d33 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#46 0x00007ffff53318d6 in js::proxy_Call(JSContext*, unsigned int, JS::Value*) () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#47 0x00007ffff5192085 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#48 0x00007ffff5185282 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#49 0x00007ffff518456f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#50 0x00007ffff519216c in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#51 0x00007ffff52f9a5f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#52 0x00007ffff5191fdc in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#53 0x00007ffff5195e12 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#54 0x00007ffff53318d6 in js::proxy_Call(JSContext*, unsigned int, JS::Value*) () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#55 0x00007ffff5192085 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#56 0x00007ffff5185282 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#57 0x00007ffff518456f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#58 0x00007ffff519216c in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#59 0x00007ffff5195d33 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#60 0x00007ffff53318d6 in js::proxy_Call(JSContext*, unsigned int, JS::Value*) () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#61 0x00007ffff5192085 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#62 0x00007ffff5185282 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#63 0x00007ffff518456f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#64 0x00007ffff519216c in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#65 0x00007ffff51a00aa in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#66 0x00007ffff518a9fd in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#67 0x00007ffff518456f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#68 0x00007ffff519216c in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#69 0x00007ffff52f9bed in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#70 0x00007ffff5191fdc in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#71 0x00007ffff5195e12 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#72 0x00007ffff53318d6 in js::proxy_Call(JSContext*, unsigned int, JS::Value*) () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#73 0x00007ffff5192085 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#74 0x00007ffff5185282 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#75 0x00007ffff518456f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#76 0x00007ffff519216c in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#77 0x00007ffff5303697 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#78 0x00007ffff5191fdc in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#79 0x00007ffff5185282 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#80 0x00007ffff518456f in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#81 0x00007ffff519216c in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#82 0x00007ffff5195d33 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#83 0x00007ffff52d4bea in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#84 0x00007ffff4ed6502 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#85 0x00007ffff4f2a240 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#86 0x00007ffff4f297a7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#87 0x00007ffff4daf3e9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#88 0x00007ffff4d23400 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#89 0x00007ffff4d34c1c in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#90 0x00007ffff4d7d3e6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#91 0x00007ffff543e132 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#92 0x00007ffff557d965 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#93 0x00007ffff560f6ae in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#94 0x00007ffff56229c8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#95 0x00007ffff5620f4c in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#96 0x00007ffff5620ce8 in XRE_main () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
#97 0x0000000000410151 in ?? ()
#98 0x000000000040c714 in ?? ()
#99 0x00007ffff6fb2790 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#100 0x000000000040fdd9 in _start ()

========================
Gdb on Evolution:
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from evolution...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/evolution 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

(evolution:5616): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: The property GtkSettings:gtk-button-images is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.

(evolution:5616): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
[New Thread 0x7fffd3fff700 (LWP 5629)]
[New Thread 0x7fff74dec700 (LWP 5658)]

(evolution:5616): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: The property GtkSettings:gtk-menu-images is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
[New Thread 0x7fff577fe700 (LWP 5661)]
[New Thread 0x7fff56805700 (LWP 5722)]
[New Thread 0x7fff57fff700 (LWP 5660)]
[New Thread 0x7fff755ed700 (LWP 5657)]
[New Thread 0x7fff75dee700 (LWP 5656)]
[New Thread 0x7fff765ef700 (LWP 5655)]
[New Thread 0x7fff76df0700 (LWP 5654)]
[New Thread 0x7fff775f1700 (LWP 5653)]
[New Thread 0x7fff77df2700 (LWP 5650)]
[New Thread 0x7fff7c988700 (LWP 5645)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd201b700 (LWP 5642)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd291e700 (LWP 5641)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd8d0b700 (LWP 5628)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd950c700 (LWP 5627)]
[New Thread 0x7fffda7c7700 (LWP 5626)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7de63e1 in _dl_relocate_object () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7de63e1 in _dl_relocate_object () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#1  0x00007ffff7dee5a9 in dl_open_worker () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#2  0x00007ffff7de9f94 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#3  0x00007ffff7dede01 in _dl_open () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x00007fffebe86fc9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libdl.so.2
#5  0x00007ffff7de9f94 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x00007fffebe875e1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libdl.so.2
#7  0x00007fffebe87061 in dlopen () from /usr/lib/libdl.so.2
#8  0x00007ffff0b8e982 in g_module_open () from /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
#9  0x00007ffff603caf9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0
#10 0x00007ffff603cd2b in ?? () from /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0
#11 0x00007ffff5768ba7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff5764768 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff5764f26 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0
#14 0x00007ffff4fa690e in ?? () from /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0
#15 0x00007ffff573f1b6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0
#16 0x00007ffff4fcc6d7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0
#17 0x00007ffff4fcd478 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0
#18 0x00007ffff3cc8f17 in g_type_create_instance () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007ffff3cac867 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007ffff3cae6a5 in g_object_new_valist () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#21 0x00007ffff3cae9e1 in g_object_new () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#22 0x00007fffd095ea81 in ?? () from /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-mail.so
#23 0x00007ffff3caca04 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#24 0x00007ffff3cae6a5 in g_object_new_valist () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#25 0x00007ffff3cae9e1 in g_object_new () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#26 0x00007fff7e12fced in ?? () from /usr/lib/evolution/modules/module-mail.so
#27 0x00007ffff3caca04 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#28 0x00007ffff3cae6a5 in g_object_new_valist () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#29 0x00007ffff3cae9e1 in g_object_new () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#30 0x00007ffff7bc3f2f in ?? () from /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-shell.so
#31 0x00007fff7e13289b in ?? () from /usr/lib/evolution/modules/module-mail.so
#32 0x00007ffff3caca04 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#33 0x00007ffff3cae6a5 in g_object_new_valist () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#34 0x00007ffff3cae9e1 in g_object_new () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#35 0x00007ffff7bc67e4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-shell.so
#36 0x00007ffff7bc6257 in e_shell_window_get_shell_view () from /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-shell.so
#37 0x00007ffff7bc70b8 in e_shell_window_set_active_view () from /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-shell.so
#38 0x00007ffff7bc7a66 in ?? () from /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-shell.so
#39 0x00007ffff3caf7db in g_object_set_property () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#40 0x00007ffff3fa6b03 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#41 0x00007ffff3fa96e0 in g_settings_bind_with_mapping () from /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0
#42 0x00007ffff3fa99fa in g_settings_bind () from /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0
#43 0x00007ffff7bc8e13 in e_shell_window_private_constructed () from /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-shell.so
#44 0x00007ffff7bc5bcc in ?? () from /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-shell.so
#45 0x00007ffff3caca04 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#46 0x00007ffff3cae6a5 in g_object_new_valist () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#47 0x00007ffff3cae9e1 in g_object_new () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#48 0x00007ffff7bc5cbb in e_shell_window_new () from /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-shell.so
#49 0x00007ffff7bb7049 in e_shell_create_shell_window () from /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-shell.so
#50 0x000000000040398f in ?? ()
#51 0x00007ffff39d290d in g_main_context_dispatch () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#52 0x00007ffff39d2ce0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#53 0x00007ffff39d3002 in g_main_loop_run () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#54 0x00007ffff446d055 in gtk_main () from /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0
#55 0x00000000004036a8 in main ()
(gdb)
```

Anyone has any idea what's going on? My next step would be to recompile glibc, but I might as well reinstall the whole system then (and obviously would rather not). Please let me know if you need more information of any kind.

Comment: Perhaps you need to upgrade GTK or its Glib (which is *not* glibc)

Comment: It sounds like you may have been performing partial upgrades. When you say you upgraded your system, what command did you run?

Comment: `sudo pacman -Syu` and `yaourt -Syua` is ran, both claiming everythings up to date

Comment: Do you have any of the testing repositories enabled?

Comment: Nope, only core, extra, community and multilib. Plus infinality-bundle and -fonts, but I doubt those affect anything :/

Comment: I'm completely stuck at this one, and feel I should find more specific information in order to get help from others, so I'm happy to get tips on where I should be looking! Should I go deeper with gdb and backtrace? Should I try to recompile glibc/glib/gtk/ld? Give up and reinstall the whole system?

Comment: This seems pretty clearly unrelated to glibc to me and related to gtk. Did gtk recently get an update for you? Are firefox or evolution built from-source on your machine?